# Select values from a table where Ids are in json format in another table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, laravel

I have a table named `journal_details` and it has a column named `transaction_by_to`. I am saving  `account_head_id` values as `json_encode` format in `transaction_by_to` in table `journal_details`. Now I want to run a select query to get account head names from `account_heads` where `transaction_by_to` ids in JSON format will find the id from `account_heads`. In the controller, I tried something like bellow, but it's getting only one. But I want to show all from `account_heads` for all JSON formatted ids.

```
public function ledgerSubmit(Request $request)
{
    $acId       = $request->acount_head;
    $startDate  = Carbon::parse($request->start_date)->format('Y-m-d');
    $endDate    = Carbon::parse($request->end_date)->format('Y-m-d');
    $reportType = $request->report_type;

    $nameOfAccount = AccountHead::find($acId);
            $ledgers = DB::table('journal_details')
                    ->join('journals', 'journal_details.journal_id', '=', 'journals.id')
                    ->join('account_heads', 'journal_details.account_head_id', '=', 'account_heads.id')
                    ->where('journal_details.account_head_id', $acId)
                    ->select('journals.number as journalNo', 'journals.journal_date as journalDate', 'journal_details.*', 'account_heads.name as nameOfAccount')
                    ->get();

    if (count($ledgers)) {
            $transactionByToId = $ledgers[0]->transaction_by_to;

            foreach (json_decode($transactionByToId) as $tId) {
                $transactionByTo = AccountHead::where('id', $tId)->get();
            }
    }
return view('report.ledger.searched-result', compact('reportType', 'startDate', 'endDate', 'ledgers', 'transactionByTo', 'nameOfAccount'));
}
```

And in blade view-

```
@foreach($ledgers as $ledger)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $loop->index + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $ledger->journalNo }}</td>
            <td>{{ date('jS F, Y', strtotime($ledger->journalDate)) }}</td>
            <td>{{ $ledger->nameOfAccount }}</td>
            <td>
                {{ $transactionByTo[0]->name }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ number_format($ledger->debit, 2,".",",") }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ number_format($ledger->credit, 2,".",",") }}
            </td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

`["16","17","7","11"]` is `transaction_by_to` column values in json format in `journal_details` and these ids are `id` for `account_heads` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your code, like in following code:

```
foreach (json_decode($transactionByToId) as $tId) {
   $transactionByTo = AccountHead::where('id', $tId)->get();
}
```

it will always keep single value, the last value. So it will seem that there is only one record.

But why don't you do following to get all records at a time:

```
  $accountHeadIds = json_decode($transactionByToId, true);
  $accountHeads = AccountHead::whereIn('id', $accountHeadIds)->get();
```

Secondly, I don't see you are processing Account Head variable (as per my code example, `$accountHeads`) in the view file that is not part of `$leders` variable. If you want to have that under `$ledgers` variable then you should store under it.

Note: I haven't tested the code above, but the concept is similar.